# Maclaurin series problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

I can't seem to understand the full solution
Why did they post x=0.2?

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $f(0.2)=\sqrt{1.2}=\sqrt{1+0.2}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason they plug $0.2$ into the function is because that is what gives them the answer they seek.

If you define $f(x) = \sqrt{1 + x}$, then $f(0.2) = \sqrt{1+0.2} = \sqrt{1.2}$, as desired.

Answer (score 2):

The goal is to evaluate $\sqrt{1.2}$. We have a Maclaurin series available for $\sqrt{1+x}$. To find $\sqrt{1.2}$, we substitute $x = 0.2$, so that  $\sqrt{1+x}|_{x=0.2} = \sqrt{1+0.2} = \sqrt{1.2}$

Answer (score 1):

They are computing $\sqrt{1.2}=\sqrt{1+0.2}$ using the Maclaurin series for $\sqrt{1+x}$. The series, with $\color{#C00000}{\text{remainder}}$, is
$$
1+\frac{\frac12}{1}x+\frac{-\frac14}{1\cdot2}x^2+\frac{\frac38}{1\cdot2\cdot3}x^3+\frac{-\frac{15}{16}}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4}x^4+\color{#C00000}{\frac{\frac{105}{32}(1+c)^{-9/2}}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5}x^5}
$$
where $c\in[0,x]$. Plugging in $x=0.2$ gives an answer of $1.0954375$ with a maximum error of $\color{#C00000}{8.75\times10^{-6}}$.